# How to prevent showing loading indicator when data was already fetched

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java2

The situation:

- We perform some api requests (rx `Single`s) in a `ViewModel`, using Retrofit. We show a loading indicator in `doOnSubscribe`.
- Now we navigate forwards and back. This causes the observer (fragment/view) to re-subscribe.
- The api calls are not performed again, but `doOnSubscribe` is called, making the progress indicator show for a very short moment.

Note that the results are not being persisted. The only cache is the in memory data (the `Single` itself).

The question:

How can we show the indicator only when the requests are being performed?

Possible solutions:

- Make Retrofit return a state object (a sealed class with "started", "loading", "result(value)" or similar) instead of the payload directly. I assume this can be done in some sort of middleware but don't know which/how.
- Show the loader when the request takes long, e.g. more than a second. This is easier to implement but doesn't seem ideal as there would be a short time where it doesn't show anything and flickering becomes more likely as it may finish right after the initial delay.
- Something simpler?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code it's hard to answer this, but let me try.
It seems right that the indicator is shown in `doOnSubscribe()` and removed in whatever you call when data fetching has completed, a `onResult()` or `onSuccess()`method I assume (it's been a while since I worked with Rx).
So when you navigate to the specific fragment/activity the method is called, so that is correct.

So in order to prevent that you could

a) just show the loading indicator delayed, so it wouldn't be visible when the result comes from memory (not so great but sure works)

b) make sure that you don't reuse the Single data, e.g. by clearing it when navigating away (this will probably lead to a api call every time, which is unnecessary, so it's also not so great)

c) don't show the indicator in `doOnSubscribe()` but only when executing the api call, so it wouldn't pop up when the results are already local.

d) store the results in another field so you don't rely on the single, or add a flag when you've already executed the api call (depends on your code if any of that makes sense here)

Comment: Thanks! Adding code felt like noise in this case as it's a very general use case, but I may do it later. Questions: a) what exactly do you mean with delayed? c) This would be like what I described with "loading" etc. state object by retrofit, as there's no way to know from the "outside" whether the api call is executing apparently

Comment: delayed - the simplest approach would look like this:
`Handler().postDelayed({
            // show your indicator here
        }, 100)
`
This would show the indicator after 100ms - you might need a flag to check if at that time it is still necessary depending on your code, sou don't show it after the code hiding it is already run.

I f you are using Kotlin it might also be possible to use custom setters to to turn on and off the indicator (again, depends on how your code looks like).

Comment: about the state object - yes and no. You can do it like that - generally a good idea - but maybe for this use case a little much overhead. What I meant is in your `doOnSubscribe()`you you check whether or not your data is already present and if not you do the api call ( and show the indicator), otherwise you just proceed.

Comment: But how would I check whether the data is already present in `doOnSubscribe()` if it's fetched in the Observable's subscription? Like I wrote, there's no separate cache / variable / persistence. I'll add the code later, it will become clearer probably.